# Spark SQL bug:DataFrame.withcolumn() could duplicate column already exists

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When creating `DataFrame.withcolumn()`,Spark dev team forgot to check it that column name is already in use.

In the beginning:

```
val res = sqlContext.sql("select * from tag.tablename where dt>20150501 limit 1").withColumnRenamed("tablename","tablename")
res.columns
```

shows:

```
res6: Array[String] = Array(user_id, service_type_id, tablename, dt)
```

then

```
val res1 = res.withColumn("tablename",res("tablename")+1)
res1.columns
```

shows:

```
res7: Array[String] = Array(user_id, service_type_id, tablename, dt, tablename)
```

By the way, `res1.show` works.

BUG begins here:

```
res1.select("tablename")

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Ambiguous references to tablename: (tablename#48,List()),(tablename#53,List());
```

Comment: this should be reported in JIRA of spark, instead of StackOverflow

Comment: They've already fixed it -- I've linked the relevant JIRA as an answer. However, this is good advice: I've found the Spark SQL team to be very responsive to tickets I've filed. Search also works quite well on the ASF JIRA site -- it was the second result when I searched on `dataframe withcolumn`. (Actually, it rang a bell because I noticed the checkin fixing it some time ago.)

Answer (score 2):

This has already been reported as [SPARK-6635](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6635). It's already been fixed, and seems set to be released in Spark 1.4.0.

Comment: found another one and submitted to JIRA but several days later no response. what to do now?

Comment: Which one is it? I haven't had this experience so I'm not sure. You could try to use the Spark developers mailing list to try to get someone interested. See [here](https://spark.apache.org/community.html).

Comment: SPARK-7428. not sure if I submit this jira in right way